# Tokenize string using sregex_token_iterator in case with heading space

Tags: c++, token

I usually use sregex_token_iterator in case split text

```
vector<string> split(const string& input, const string& reText) {
    regex re(reText);
    sregex_token_iterator first{input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1}, last;
    return {first, last};
}

auto text = string(" hello world, hi every one");
auto delimiters = string("[\\s,]+");
auto arr = split(text, delimiters);
copy(begin(arr), end(arr), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

But, with heading space " " the result is,

{"", "hello", "world", "hi", every", "one" }

So, I usually remove heading "" empty string manually.

```
if (arr.size() > 0 && arr[0].empty()) arr.erase(arr.begin());
```

Is there a better idea?

Comment: You could trim the string before splitting it. Then you won't have leading/trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I did here was change your delimiter list so that it matches series of characters which do not contain those delimiters, then I changed your iterator to do matching instead of not matching.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> split2(const std::string& input, const std::string& reText) {
    std::regex re(reText);
    std::sregex_token_iterator first{input.begin(), input.end(), re, 0}, last;
    return {first, last};
}

int main() {
    std::string text = " hello world, hi every one";
    std::string delimiters = "[^\\s,]+";
    auto arr = split2(text, delimiters);
    for(const auto& s : arr) {
        std::cout << '"' << s << "\"\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"hello"
"world"
"hi"
"every"
"one"
```